# Best way to define Android layout files for multiple devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the standard/best way to define sizing for elements in Android layout files to account for Android devices with all types of screens?

For example:  I've been using a LinearLayout to arrange multiple child elements (TextViews, Buttons) one after the other horizontally or vertically for a ListView.  However, on a smaller device, I may want to scale the elements down or shrink some elements but keep the others fixed.

I'd appreciate input.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an entry in the android dev guide for that: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can use drawables in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi`. Test those in different screens in the emulator and tweak the sizes appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Please read [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

In a nutshell: It's very easy. You can create subfolders of each folder in the resources (like layout-small, layout-large, layout-hdpi), and add different versions of your layout. The system will always fall back to the layout folder if none of your specializations (hdpi, large, etc) match.